DeviceActivityMonitorExtension is not getting called
I’m trying to implement app blocking with a time limit in my React Native project’s iOS native module using Swift, but I’m having trouble even though I created a DeviceActivityMonitorExtension , set up an app group in Xcode and added the Family-Controls capability.
Tried everything here but it didn't change anything
iOS native module file :
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FamilyControls
import React
import DeviceActivity
import ManagedSettings
import UserNotifications


class GlobalSelection {
    static let shared = GlobalSelection()
    
    var selection = FamilyActivitySelection()

    private init() {}
}

extension DeviceActivityName{
  static let daily = Self("daily")
}

@objc(DeviceActivityMonitorModule)
class DeviceActivityMonitorModule: NSObject {
  
  private let store = ManagedSettingsStore()

  @objc
  func startMonitoring(_ limitInMinutes: Int) {
          
    let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(
      intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0),
      intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59),
      repeats: true
    )
    
    let threshold = DateComponents(minute: limitInMinutes)
    
    // Create an event for the time limit
    let dailyEvent = DeviceActivityEvent(
      applications: GlobalSelection.shared.selection.applicationTokens, threshold: threshold
    )
    
    
    let eventName = DeviceActivityEvent.Name("dailyLimitEvent")
        
    // Register the monitor with the activity name and schedule
    do {
      try DeviceActivityCenter().startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule, events: [eventName: dailyEvent])
      print("24/7 Monitoring started with time limit : \(limitInMinutes) m")
      
    } catch {
        print("Failed to start monitoring: \(error)")
    }
  
    
  }
  
  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}



Extension file :

import DeviceActivity
import UserNotifications
import ManagedSettings


// Optionally override any of the functions below.
// Make sure that your class name matches the NSExtensionPrincipalClass in your Info.plist.
class DeviceActivityMonitorExtension: DeviceActivityMonitor {
  let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
  
  func scheduleNotification(with title: String) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = title // Using the custom title here
                content.body = "Here is the body text of the notification."
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                
                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false) // 5 seconds from now
                
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MyNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
                
                center.add(request) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Permission denied. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
        }
    }
  
    override func intervalDidStart(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalDidStart(for: activity)
        scheduleNotification(with: "interval did start")
    }
    
    override func intervalDidEnd(for activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.intervalDidEnd(for: activity)
        
        scheduleNotification(with: "interval did start")
    }
    
    override func eventDidReachThreshold(_ event: DeviceActivityEvent.Name, activity: DeviceActivityName) {
        super.eventDidReachThreshold(event, activity: activity)
        scheduleNotification(with: "event did reach threshold warning")
    
    }
    
}


